# Sublime Text 3 how to change the font size of the file sidebar?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Though I have tried to modify "font.size" in classes like "Label_control" and "sidebar_control" in the Package "Theme-Default", the font size of the editor does not change at all. Is there anything different in sublime text3？

Comment: facing same issue., tried all solutions listed below., no help

Comment: See this answer for how to get to the Default.sublime-theme file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23046654/52817

Comment: Just a side comment as this was already properly answered. I've been using Boxy Theme and looking into how to do this, if you are using Boxy, you can open Boxy Configuration and configure font size for tabs, sidebar and do a lot of config there easily.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The answers are omitting the **square brackets**, in the case one is creating the file from scratch.

To recap, for the ST3 users who don't have the `Default.sublime-theme` file (which is actually the default configuration), the simplest procedure is:

1. Navigate to Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Browse Packages
2. Open the `User` directory
3. Create a file named `Default.sublime-theme` (if you're using the default theme, otherwise use the theme name, e.g. `Material-Theme-Darker.sublime-theme`) with the following content (modify `font.size` as required):

---

```
[
    {
        "class": "sidebar_label",
        "color": [0, 0, 0],
        "font.bold": false,
        "font.size": 12
    },
]
```

For reference, [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/89867e9cb63f7e811a39) there is the full file (as found in ST2).

**Ubuntu 18.04**

Location of theme setting on Ubuntu 18.04, installed via `sudo apt install sublime-text`:

```
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Default.sublime-theme
```

**MacOS**

Location of theme setting on MacOS, installed via DMG:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User/Default.sublime-theme
```

Comment: needed to add the complete config from https://gist.github.com/anonymous/89867e9cb63f7e811a39 to get it working.

Comment: As per @nate-flink said, filename should be same as your current theme. I am using [Material-Theme-Darker](https://dribbble.com/shots/2104476-Material-Theme-for-Sublime-Text-3) so I create `Material-Theme-Darker.sublime-theme` file under `User` folder.

Comment: I'm using ST3 with Color Sublime, so I had to leave the file name as Default.sublime-theme instead of the Color Sublime theme name.

Comment: When changing the `"font.size"` I also recommend changing `"sidebar_tree", "row_padding"`. I use `[0,1]`. See the [linked](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/89867e9cb63f7e811a39) ST2 file for syntax.

Comment: Only drawback here is that with fileicons enabled, these get stretched out too making it look pretty nasty: https://puu.sh/rd0TA/0600aa5ae9.png

Comment: I used Solarized (Light), and creating a `Solarized-(Light).sublime-theme` file didn't work. Using `Default.sublime-theme` did.

Comment: This answer, now accepted, assumes the reader saw other answers first and is thus highly confusing to a new reader like me. *"The answers are omitting the square brackets"* - what? Which answers? Which brackets? *"... in the case one is creating the file from scratch"* - huh? Which file? *"To recap"* - what?! But this is the first thing I've read on this topic! *"or the ST3 users who don't have the `Default.sublime-theme` file"* - aah, what? How do I know if I have this file? A sentence and a half in, I'm already bewildered and unsure if the rest of this answer is relevant to me.

Answer (score 108):

On Ubuntu, for versions of Sublime **older than 3.2**, what worked for me was changing the dpi scale in Preferences > Settings — User by adding this line:

```
"dpi_scale": 1.10
```

For Sublime **3.2**, you can use the following line instead:

```
"ui_scale": 1.10
```

Adjust the scale value as needed. After this change, you have to restart Sublime Text for it to take effect.

Comment: This is a better solution if the whole UI is looking small (for example, when using a 4k display). I used a value of `1.5` under Ubuntu+XFCE.

Comment: Simplest solution, but note that you have to restart Sublime Text for it to take effect.

Comment: This seems like it should be the correct answer, because it should persist even if you change the theme.

Comment: In windows, this setting introduces line spacing some may not like. Use the  [line_padding_top] and [line_padding_bottom] preferences to remove. For example, if you scale to 1.5, set both padding to values to -1.5. This will remove the spacing.

Comment: @gravidThoughts I encountered the same problem, although in my case there was also an increased width spacing between characters in a line. Setting line padding options solved the problem with line spacing, but not the problem with character spacing. Through experimenting with settings I figured out the solution to both problems: "font_options": ["gdi"]
At least it works in my case (Windows 10)

Comment: @DemoniacDeath Thanks for the tip.

Comment: From Sublime 3.2 it's called `ui_scale` instead.

Comment: @Asaf thanks, thats so helpful.  For months i've been mildly annoyed by this using it on my 4k.

Comment: Awesome ui_scale setting. This is an excellent setting for 4k!

Comment: `ui_scale` worked like a charm, thanks!
As mentioned, it did require a restart, though

Answer (score 21):

I'm using Sublime Text 3.2.1, a 4k display and a Mac. Tab titles and the sidebar are difficult to read with default ST3 settings. I used the menus Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Settings which opens two files: Preferences.sublime-settings--Default and Preferences.sublime-settings--User.

You can only edit the User file. The Default file is useful for showing what variables you can set. Around line 350 of the Default file are two variables as shown below:

```
// Magnifies the entire user interface. Sublime Text must be restarted for
// this to take effect.
"ui_scale": 1.0,

// Linux only. Sets the app DPI scale - a decimal number such as 1.0, 1.5,
// 2.0, etc. A value of 0 auto-detects the DPI scale. Sublime Text must be
// restarted for this to take effect.
"dpi_scale": 0,
```

`"dpi_scale": 3.0` did nothing on my Mac `"ui_scale": 1.5` worked well. The following is my User file.

```
{
    "dictionary": "Packages/Language - English/en_US.dic",
    "font_size": 17,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "theme": "Default.sublime-theme",
    "ui_scale": 1.5
}
```

Comment: `dpi_scale` seems to be entirely removed now (Sublime 3.2.2 on Ubuntu). `ui_scale`, on the other hand, still works perfectly for me.

Comment: ST 3.2.2 on OS X - `ui_scale` is working as expected

Comment: Thanks for this.  I think this is a better option than changing filesize, because if the font is too big the line spacing gets in the way.  Whereas with this method the space is correct and the font looks bigger and easier to read.  Also on a 4k monitor.

Answer (score 19):

Navigate to Sublime Text>Preferences>Browse Packages. You should see a file tree.

In the Packages folder, you should see

Theme - Default > Default.sublime-theme (substitute Default for your theme name)

Open that file and find the "class": "sidebar_label: entry and add "font.size".

example:

```
    {
        "class": "sidebar_label",
        "color": [0, 0, 0],
        "font.bold": false,
        "font.size": 14
    },
```

Comment: @Jails: I can confirm that it does indeed with with ST3.

Comment: There no Theme Default in: "Sublime Text>Preferences>Browse Package" at least with the latest SL3 ?!

Comment: Because we need to use PackageResourceViewer, I think the answer needs to be updated.

Comment: @Jails Amazing! thanks for that, it worked like charm, in ST3 the method marked as answer here didn't worked for me as now packages are packed, and I needed what you suggested in order to view and edit the file :D! your suggestion should be the answer!

Comment: thenks worked for me ! `sublime 3` with `Material Theme`

Answer (score 19):

I followed these instructions but then found that the **menu hover color** was wrong.

I am using the **Spacegray theme** in Sublime 3 beta 3074. So to accomplish the sidebar font color change and also hover color change, on OSX, I created a new file 
~/Library/"Application Support"/"Sublime Text 3"/Packages/User/Spacegray.sublime-theme

then added this code to it:

```
[
    {
        "class": "sidebar_label",
        "color": [192,197,203],
        "font.bold": false,
        "font.size": 15
    },
     {
        "class": "sidebar_label",
        "parents": [{"class": "tree_row","attributes": ["hover"]}],
        "color": [255,255,255] 
    },
]
```

It is possible to tweak many other settings for your theme if you can see the original default:

https://gist.github.com/nateflink/0355eee823b89fe7681e

I extracted this file from the sublime package zip file by installing the PackageResourceViewer following MattDMo's instructions (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426065/mattdmo) here:

[How to change default code snippets in Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190392/how-to-change-default-code-snippets-in-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score 7):

To change the font name use

```
  "font.face": "Liberation Mono"
```

in this file, in my case with ST3 Default.sublime-theme

Comment: Great! Looking for it

Comment: I like `Ubuntu Mono` way better

Answer (score 6):

In my case using (**Sublime Text 3.0**) just adding one more thing with font size, I also given padding and indent inside the sidebar becuase it wasn't looking good. Now ***Looking much better now***

[image: > BEFORE]

> > 3 simple steps

[image]

> copy the content and past right hand side.

```
[ 
    { 
        "class": "sidebar_label",
        "font.size": 18 
    }, 
    {
        "class": "sidebar_tree",
        "row_padding": [9, 10],
        "indent": 12,
        "indent_offset": 12,
    }, 
]
```

[image]

Comment: I found that I had to make changes in the theme settings, which can be found through Preferences > Customize Theme, rather than in color scheme settings, but I am using version 4. See https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/themes.html.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change it at `"class": "sidebar_label"`
Example, in your .sublime-theme file:

```
// Sidebar entry
{
    "class": "sidebar_label",
    "color": [212, 212, 213],
    "shadow_offset": [0, 0],
    "font.size":13
}
```

[Credit](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4799)

Comment: Thats the SublimeText 3 theme default on my machine :
https://gist.github.com/daslicht/eede77db7094e8518d5b
There is no such entry ?

Answer (score 3):

Default.sublime-theme file works unless you have installed a theme. If you did, go to your theme's github repo and download the your_theme.sublime-theme file and put it in your 'User' folder. 
In that file, find `"class": "sidebar_label",` add `"font.size":16` to that section.

Answer (score 2):

Some limited flexibility is available if your using the [Afterglow Theme](http://yabatadesign.github.io/afterglow-theme/).

https://github.com/YabataDesign/afterglow-theme

You can edit your user preferences in the following way.

Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Settings - User:

```
{
    "sidebar_size_14": true
}
```

https://github.com/YabataDesign/afterglow-theme#sidebar-size-options

Answer (score 1):

I use Soda Dark 3 with icons enabled. So by just renaming it erases all the icons enabled with it. So I just leave the Default as it is and created a new file `Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme` and just have the following in the content

```
[
{
    "class": "label_control",
    "color": [150, 25, 25],
    "shadow_color": [24, 24, 24],
    "shadow_offset": [0, -1],
    "font.size": 16,
    "font.bold": true
},
```

]

So in Mac is it at `/Users/gugovind/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/`

Answer (score 1):

In Sublime 3, there is a simpler way using UI and menus.

Go to Preferences->Font->Larger

The keyboard shortcut is `Command+`, note that you have to press Shift to get plus on most keyboards.

I've used this on Mac. It might be different on Windows.

Comment: Doesn't work for the left menu.

Comment: Doesn't work for the left menu

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the font size then simply follow.
 **Preferences-> Default File preferences.**

After clicking on **default file preferences**, new *Tab* will open with name of **Default File Type.Sublime-options**

After find **Font** properties like ***font Courier New 12***
we (recommend to use CTRL+F) then change size of it. Click save and **instantly** you can see the changes.

Comment: I can't find **Preferences-> Default File preferences** on ST3

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the default theme. Just goto Preferences-> Default File Preferences 
A new tab pops up.
At about line number you could see the font  [font-name]  [font-size]

Edit the font-size according to your wish and save.

Answer (score -2):

Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Setting:

[image: Sublime Text -> Preferences -> setting]

Write your style in right screen:

[image: Write your style in right screen]

Comment: This changes the font size of the main editor region, not the sidebar.