# How to change default code snippets in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I know how to edit the snippets myself, just can't seem to be able to find the default ones in the new version of Sublime Text.

**EDIT**: The snippet I am trying to find and consequently edit is the default for the Latex files, in particular the one that converts from:

```
sec
```

to

```
\section{section name} % (fold)
\label{sec:section_name}
```

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Sublime Text 3 stores its packages in `.sublime-package` zip files (the location varies by OS), so unlike ST2 you can't just go to the `Packages` folder and see everything. However, there is an excellent plugin called [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) (available via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/)) that can, among other things, extract files or whole packages to the `Packages` directory.

Once you've installed the plugin:

- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette
- type ***`prv`*** to get the `Package Resource Viewer:` options
- select **`Package Resource Viewer: Open Resource`**
- navigate down the list to `LaTeX`
- then open the `section-..-(section).sublime-snippet` file.

You should now be able to edit this file and save it, which will create a new file `Packages/LaTeX/section-..-(section).sublime-snippet` that you can open directly via the file menu if you need to alter it again.

If you'd like to work on multiple files, or an entire package, use `Package Resource Viewer: Extract Package` which will unzip everything into the `Packages/PackageName` folder. Please keep in mind, though, that once packages or individual files are extracted into the `Packages` folder, they overrule files of the same name located in the `.sublime-package` archive. This is good for customization, but if at some point the parent package is updated, you won't see the effects because they're being masked by what's in `Packages`. Therefore, it's probably best to extract only what you need, and keep an eye on your package updates in case new features are introduced that you want to take advantage of.

Comment: Sounds great. I am wondering though why Sublime does not ship it's own package manager by default and why you have to play around with Python code just to get it...

Comment: @Domi - Python is the language of Sublime's internal API, and all plugins need to have at least a Python wrapper, if not be completely written in it. You'll have to ask Jon Skinner why he didn't include a package manager with Sublime, but seeing as Package Control is the *de facto* standard, with no competition that I know of, it's not really a huge issue.

Comment: Added a little more info related to this in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288870/sublime-text-3-how-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-file-sidebar/28909217#28909217

Comment: Is there any way to do this without having to worry about your settings getting overwritten when updating? Could you put it in the User directory or something?

Comment: @GreeKatrina your settings won't get overwritten after an update. It's just that any changed files in the new version of `PackageName.sublime-package` won't be applied, as the old version you unzipped with PackageResourceViewer will be overriding it.

Comment: I would like to change the TODO Snippet, (I want to add a TM_COMMENT_START before "TODO". I know than one solution is creating a new snippet, but: How can I find this snipped with PackageResourceViewer?  Thanks!!

Comment: @AlbertCatalà what package provides that snippet? It is not part of the base packages.

Comment: This snippet comes with ST by default, If I knew the package, I could change it

Comment: @AlbertCatalà it is not part of build 3103, the latest version of Sublime Text 3 (public beta), or build 3107, the latest dev build. I searched every single package for a case-insensitive match to `"todo"`, and nothing relevant matched. Therefore, it must be from a plugin, or else you are using an outdated version of Sublime.

Comment: This answer is old but still very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

To easily jump there in terminal (if you are using ST3 on OSX) is `/Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User`. You can see all of your snippets here and edit them as you like.

Comment: Just to be clear, while this is good info, this is not *all* the snippets, especially not the default snippets, which are embedded elsewhere. This would be the location where you would put yours though. Selected answer by @MattDMo is the way to edit *default* snippets incl. those added by other packages.

Comment: I was trying to find out how to change the Line Highlight and Selected Text Highlight and this solution worked great for me! I have a weird monitor where at different angles I cannot see what I have highlighted, simple changed to a different tint via http://www.color-hex.com/. yay! Thanks!

Comment: This is the simplest, most straightforward answer for editing your own snippets.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, here is how to do it
without having to install any additional plugin.

### Solution not requiring any additional plugin (October 2016).

---

I had a similar problem while trying to override some key bindings defined in a package.

### Steps

- Install your package (using Package Manager or any other method you prefer).

Your zipped package file should be now placed within the folder `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/<your-package>.sublime-package`.

- Check the content of the package by unzipping it (just make sure to keep the original zipped file).

  Among these files, find the one that contains the preference you want to edit (see [Package Contents](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#package-contents)). In your case it should be a `.sublime-snippet` file. Remember its name.
- Create a folder with the same name of your package inside `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`.
- Create inside this folder a new snippet file that will override the default package behaviour. Note that the new file should have the same name of the snippet file that you found inside the package. From console:

  ```
    > cd ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages
    > mkdir <YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME>
    > gedit <YOUR-SNIPPET-NAME>.sublime-snippet
  ```
- Put the content of your new snippet in your `<YOUR-SNIPPET-NAME>.sublime-snippet`. This will override the old snippet behaviour.

**Sources:**

- [How To Override Sublime Text Packages Shortcuts and Preferences](https://www.keenformatics.com/how-to-override-sublime-text-3-shortcuts-and-preferences/) (my blog)
- [How To Find out Sublime Text Key Binding Commands](https://www.keenformatics.com/how-to-find-out-sublime-text-keys-commands/) (my blog)
- [ST Unofficial Documentation - Package Contents](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#package-contents)
- Personal experience

Comment: Remember that on Linux filenames are case sensitive so Packages/PHP/Snippets/function.sublime-snippet and Packages/PHP/snippets/function.sublime-snippet will create 2 different entries on auto completion list.

Answer (score 0):

#### Override with new snippet

While it's not simple to edit built-in snippets, you can add new snippets with the same trigger keyword, to effectively override them.

1. Tools > Developer > New Snippet... (in ST2 at least, I assume 3 is similar)
2. Add the snippet that you desire (check [docs](https://sublime-text.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensibility/snippets.html) for format). Ensure the `<tabTrigger>` is the same as the one you want to replace
3. Save in your User folder with extension `.sublime-snippet`
4. Restart and try it out!

After using your snippet, Sublime seems to remember your preference and be the first one selected, rather than the built in one.

[image]