# Getting LaTeX comment package comments highlighted in Sublime Text

Tags: comments, latex, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext3

This question is about Sublime Text 3 LaTeX syntax highlighting. Only LaTeX default `%` comments are recognized by Sublime Text, and it could be useful to get ST to recognize the `comment` package `\begin{comment} [...] \end{comment}` comments.

I would like to get those comment sections highlighted to improve readability (the best thing would be to change the background color).

It seems that what should be done would be to modify the `LaTeX.tmLanguage` file (using the `PackageResourceViewer` package as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190392/how-to-change-default-code-snippets-in-sublime-text-3)). I am managing small changes but can't figure how to do something complex like adding a Begin-End Rules for comments (as explained [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html)).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got there. The quick way is to paste the following xml into your `LaTeX.tmLanguage` in the `<array>` immediately following `<patterns>`:

```
    <dict>
        <key>begin</key>
        <string>\\begin\{comment\}</string>
        <key>end</key>
        <string>\\end\{comment\}</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>comment.block.latex</string>
    </dict>
```

To get there, I did something like this:

1. Get the package `PackageDev`.
2. Use that to convert the `.tmLanguage` file (you got using `PackageResourceManager`) to YAML.
3. Under `patterns:`, add something like

   ```
   - name: comment.block.latex
     begin: \\begin\{comment\}
     end: \\end\{comment\}
   ```
4. Convert it back to xml with `PackageDev`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I just made two small changes, in order for the code to work with tabbed comment blocks & have the last line fully highlighted (since my aim was to change the background color):
 
`<string>\t{0,9}\\begin\{comment\}</string>` and `<string>\\end\{comment\}(\s*\n)?</string>`