# Sublime text 3: editing in-built code completion syntax

Tags: sublimetext3

How to edit inbuilt code completion syntax in ST3?

For example:
When I work on c file, I type

```
for
```

and hit tab, it gives me this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    /* code */
}
```

This hurts my code formatting, and my eyes, what I would like is

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
    /* code */
}
```

Which file should I edit to do it when working with ST3 on Ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change default code snippets in Sublime Text 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190392/how-to-change-default-code-snippets-in-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21196293/1426065) for complete instructions on how to edit snippets in ST3. The package you are looking for is `C++`, and the snippet to edit is `030-for-int-loop-(fori).sublime-snippet`. Change it to the following:

```xml
<snippet>
    <description>For Loop</description>
    <content><![CDATA[for (int ${2:i} = 0; $2 < ${1:count}; ${3:++$2}){
    ${0:/* code */}
}]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>for</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.c, source.objc, source.c++, source.objc++</scope>
</snippet>
```

and you should be all set.