# Sublime snippet

Tags: sublimetext3, code-snippets

When I'm coding in HTML and use `input` tag, sublime autocompletion gives me `<input></input>`. I'd love sublime gives me `<input />`.

How can I change this? (my sublime is version 3)

I saw this:
[How to change default code snippets in Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190392/how-to-change-default-code-snippets-in-sublime-text-3)

and this video (portuguese audio):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iTu3C9FzX4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime's HTML autocompletions are done in a Python script.

1. Install `PackageResourceViewer` using Package Control (if it isn't already installed)
2. From the Command Palette, select `PackageResourceViewer - Open Resource`
3. Select `HTML`
4. Select `html_completions.py`
5. Find the line `('input\tTag', 'input type=\"$1\" name=\"$2\">'),`
6. Change it to `('input\tTag', 'input type=\"$1\" name=\"$2\" />'),`
7. Save the file

Comment: There's not this line in my file. I found `normal_tags = ([` with `'input'` in the middle.

Comment: which build of ST3 are you using? you can find out from the `Help` menu -> `About`

Comment: Stable Channel, Build 3103