# How do you change the folder and menu font-size in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: ide, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm not talking about the font-size of the editor window, simply the font-size of the text in the main menu bar and the folder/file navigation side panel.

[image: Screenshot of Sublime Text 3 with arrows pointing to FOLDERS pane and main menu]

I've googled all over and read through [all the docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/) I could find to no avail. Thanks in advance!

How do I do this in Windows 7?

Answer (score 5):

Sidebar and tab font are modifiable:
[Sublime Text 2 how to change the font size of the file sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781833/sublime-text-2-how-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-file-sidebar)

The package is now located at `/opt/sublime_text/Packages/Theme - Default.sublime-package` (for Linux installation).
Extract `Default.sublime-theme` to `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User` and modify the content.
(This step can be simplified using the [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) package.)

Menu font doesn't seem to be modifiable.

Comment: You can override existing files using https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer

Comment: I also came across that package in my research. Does it overwirte package in `/opt/sublime_text/Packages/` or make copy to User folder? The former modification will be lost upon an upgrade.

Comment: It creates a a folder in the `Packages` directory. It will not be lost upon upgrade. In ST3, plugins can be run directly from the `*.sublime-package` files. That is, unless you choose to override the file, it will not be lost. The default packages, as well as plugins installed through package control (generally) overwrite the sublime-package file. The Packages folder, and it's contents, will be left untouched. There is an exception to this rule with package control, as a developer can choose to have their plugin extracted. However, that doesn't apply to default packages.

Comment: I created an answer for this for Mac here, but most of it should apply to windows as well --
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288870/sublime-text-3-how-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-file-sidebar/28909217#28909217

Answer (score 2):

As far as changing the font size in the main menu bar, this can be done through the Windows Control Panel, but any changes will be universal - they'll apply to all applications.

Finding the options to change the menu font and size is kind of complicated, but here's how I do it: Open the Control Panel and select `Personalization`, then down at the bottom click on `Window Color`. In the next window that opens, click on `Advanced Appearance Settings...` to open the `Window Color and Appearance` window. Click on the menu item `Normal` and select your preferred font and size, then click **`Apply`** to check it out. Hit **`OK`** when you're done, save your theme if you want, and you're all set.