# Change Sublime sidebar font size on macOS

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

I would like to increase the font size of the left side bar in Sublime Text 3. I can't seem to find a good way to do this. I am using the default theme, and am on Mac.

Does anyone have a suggestion? I don't want to install a custom theme, but would *just* like to increase the font size of the side bar.

Thanks!

Comment: It is NOT necessary to go into the zip file, as the accepted answer suggests. Just create a simple textfile Data\Packages\User\Default.sublime-theme and only put your changes there. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25694790/362951

Comment: I tried this method, as it seemed quicker.  However, my Sublime directory structure seems to differ (Mac OSX El Cap).  I put my changes (a file called 'Default.sublime-theme') here:
'/Users/[myname]/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User'
and it had no effect/didn't seem to work, after restarting Sublime.

Comment: someone know a way to have a shortcut do this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You will need to edit the `.sublime-theme` file to do this. Unfortunately, in Sublime Text 3 this file is contained in a zipped `.sublime-package` file, so you'll need to extract that first. Install the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin via Package Control, then hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and type ***`prv`*** to bring up the PackageResourceViewer options. Select `Open Resource`, scroll down to `Theme - Default`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, scroll down to `Default.sublime-theme`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to open it.

Next, search for **`sidebar_label`** and modify the first one (on line 362) to look like this (it needs to be valid JSON):

```js
{
    "class": "sidebar_label",
    "color": [0, 0, 0],
    "font.bold": false,
    "font.italic": false, // <-- add comma
    "font.size": 14 // <-- new line
    // , "shadow_color": [250, 250, 250], "shadow_offset": [0, 0]
},
```

Save the file, and you should see the sidebar font size change. You can change `14` to whatever size you want, depending on your personal preferences.

Comment: I wonder if there is system behind this madness. Why did Sublime3 configuration become *MORE* complicated?

Comment: @Domi this is exactly the same way you configure a theme in ST2, without the package extraction step. What's your point?

Comment: @MattDMo The PRM shipped with ST2 didn't it? Either way, I have to apologize. I was upset yesterday because it took me about an hour to get this done due to invalid paths listed in the manual (on Windows, it's not the path everyone keeps repeating all over SO and Superuser; I finally stumbled upon a comment that hinted at using the console to look them up).

Comment: thanks for your answer, really helped me. One more thing, do you know, how can I enlarge the line-heigh? I changed font-size to 24 (I need so large), and lines are too close. Thanks a lot

Comment: @areim: Preferences > Settings > User, 
 "line_padding_bottom": 1,
 "line_padding_top": 1,

Comment: Editing that section of "Default.sublime-theme" actually caused my sidebar to go completely black, and show nothing. This persisted after I reverted the changes I had made. Has anyone else had this happen?

Comment: I just reinstalled Sublime Text and then followed the instructions in the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288870/sublime-text-3-how-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-file-sidebar -- basically the same as the answer above, except that you create a new user override file for the theme file, instead of editing the original. This worked for me.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on OSX.  (As you save the file you can see your changes--no restart required).

Comment: this is really ridiculously convoluted.  i love most of ST, but its documentation relies way too heavily on its user base.

Comment: It does not work for me. I opened `/opt/sublime_text/Packages/Default.sublime-package` with simply `file-roller`, but there was no `Default.sublime-theme` file. I added it with the contents 

`[ {     "class": "tab_label",     "font.size": 16,  },]`

and I restarted Sublime, but the tab text size is not changed. I'm using Sublime 3.2.1 on Lubuntu 18.0.4

Comment: I solved simply putting `"ui_scale": 1.6,` in user preferences

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this, just to add that, with sublime text 3 at least, i needed to modify the theme I use. e.g. `Flatland Dark.sublime-theme`