# How to change tab font size

Tags: sublimetext3

Already looked into *`Preferences> Settings-Default`* but I can't find anything...

How may I change the `font-size` of the tabs of opened files?

As I'm using a custom theme, is there a way to do it working with *`Preferences>Settings-User`* ?

[image]

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645565/changing-font-size-of-tabs-strip-in-sublime-text-3

Comment: Already saw that. Can't find those files in my installation folder.

Comment: You need to use the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin to access files stored in the compressed `.sublime-package` files.