# sublime text font size on size bar does not change

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, user-preferences, settings

Using sublime text 3, I have installed the material theme.

But I notice that the sidebar font size is too small.

Following the doc and searching on stack, I have change the default setting in the file named `Material-Theme-Darker.sublime-theme` and the other one named `Default.sublime-theme` like this (the two are the same):

```
[
    {"class": "tab_control", "attributes": ["selected", "file_medium_dark"],"tint_modifier": [255, 255, 255, 80]},
    {
        "class": "sidebar_label",
        "color": [0, 0, 0],
        "font.bold": false,
        "shadow_color": [250, 250, 250], "shadow_offset": [0, 0],
        "font.size": 16
    },
]
```

But nothing change. Where am I wrong ?

This my default user setting `Preferences.sublime-settings`:

```
{
    "always_show_minimap_viewport": true,
    "bold_folder_labels": true,
    "caret_extra_bottom": 6,
    "caret_extra_top": 6,
    "caret_style": "phase",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/SublimeLinter/itg.dark (SL).tmTheme",
    "default_encoding": "UTF-8",
    "default_line_ending": "unix",
    "draw_minimap_border": true,
    "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
    "fade_fold_buttons": false,
    "font-face": "Saab",
    "font_options":
    [
        "gray_antialias",
        "subpixel_antialias"
    ],
    "font_size": 15.5,
    "highlight_line": true,
    "highlight_modified_tabs": true,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "indent_guide_options":
    [
        "draw_normal",
        "draw_active"
    ],
    "indent_subsequent_lines": true,
    "line_padding_bottom": 1,
    "line_padding_top": 1,
    "match_brackets": true,
    "match_brackets_angle": false,
    "match_brackets_braces": true,
    "match_brackets_content": true,
    "match_brackets_square": true,
    "match_selection": true,
    "material_theme_bold_tab": true,
    "material_theme_compact_sidebar": true,
    "material_theme_panel_separator": true,
    "material_theme_small_tab": false,
    "material_theme_tabs_autowidth": true,
    "material_theme_tabs_separator": true,
    "material_theme_tree_headings": true,
    "overlay_scroll_bars": "enabled",
    "quick_panel_small": true,
    "save_on_focus_lost": true,
    "scroll_past_end": true,
    "scroll_speed": 1.5,
    "shift_tab_unindent": true,
    "show_encoding": true,
    "show_line_endings": true,
    "spell_check": false,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "theme": "Material-Theme-Darker.sublime-theme",
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
    "word_wrap": true
}
```

Comment: follow this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288870/sublime-text-3-how-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-file-sidebar/25694790#25694790) fixed my problem ! Thank you slack community.